# STM32 SPI and mismatched data vectors for TLE5012b encoder

Tags: stm32, spi

I am having a problem (not strictly a problem since it works but it involves a hack) with data receiving between TLE5012b encoder and STM32f401CC. I believe this is a common problem to all STM32s.
The code is part of a much larger open source project for field oriented control. It works very well. The critical piece is here, and is called from the FOC interrupt loop. It completes fast enough etc, no help needed on that front.
https://github.com/davidmolony/MESC_Firmware/blob/1a75856b664bb7589a441579c98037760931ec28/MESC_Common/Src/MESCfoc.c#L2097

[image]

```
  struct __attribute__ ((__packed__))SamplePacket{
    struct
    {
        uint8_t crc;
        uint8_t STAT_RESP; // Should be 0xF_?
    }safetyword;
uint16_t angle;
int16_t speed;
uint16_t revolutions;};
```

typedef struct SamplePacket SamplePacket;
SamplePacket pkt;

void tle5012(void){

```
  uint16_t const len = sizeof(pkt) / sizeof(uint16_t);
  uint16_t reg = (UINT16_C(  1) << 15) /* RW=Read */
               | (UINT16_C(0x0) << 11) /* Lock */
               | (UINT16_C(0x0) << 10) /* UPD=Buffer */
               | (UINT16_C(0x02) << 4) /* ADDR */
               | (len -1);            /* ND */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_8, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
  HAL_SPI_Transmit( &hspi3, (uint8_t *)&reg,   1, 1000 );
  HAL_SPI_Receive(  &hspi3, (uint8_t *)&pkt, len, 1000 );
```

The issue is that the Angle (which is confirmed in the scope shot to be the first data) ends up not in the first index of the SPI recieved vector (pkt.safetyword) but in the second (pkt.angle) It should not. I had to rearrange the struct like this to make it work.

Essentially, it appears that the first received data goes in the second index of the struct, the second data goes in the third, the third in the fourth and... the last data wraps around and ends up in the first index of the struct.

I cannot understand why. I have tried changing the amount of clocking done (number of data received in the HAL call, the pic below is a shot where I put in an extra receive to see what happenned - the TLE simply stops sending anything) using a dumb array rather than a struct, have checked that it compiles with the struct packed in order (it does) and can find no reason why this is happening.

Any ideas? Does anyone know?

It is very repeatable. I have had the motor spinning for literally millions of PWM/SPI call cycles. This routine is called 20000 times/second, synchronously with the PWM without any error. If you ever do mismatch the angle data with something else, you get an instant overcurrent event, which does not happen ever.

Comment: Could it be an optimization issue? What are your compiler settings for optimization? -O?

Comment: Maybe the SPI reads the response while sending the command and, so, everything is shifted? Are you using 3 or 4 wire SPI?

Comment: It is 3 wire SPI. Optimisation setting are o2. Unfortunately I cannot reduce the optimisation time otherwise it does not work atall (interrupt too long, I could probably make a simple sketch to test this). I do not think the SPI is overlapping the read and command send, there is a clear gap between them.